# Photo ID for domestic air travel

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, india

I have no photo ID issued by Government with me. Can I use an Affidavit with photo  duly sworn in before Notary can be A valid Photo ID. Is there  any  specific  language for such Affidavit.

Travel is domestic in India.

Comment: Do you have a nationalized bank passbook? Aadhar (e-Aadhar eill work), PAN card?